# GROUP BY with an ordering

Tags: mysql, sql

`SELECT * FROM title` gives me the following output:

```
title_number    version_type    hd_sd
1000046         Standard    SD
1000046         Standard    HD
1000050         Standard    SD
1000093         Standard    SD
1000093         Standard    HD
1000125         Standard    SD
1000269         Standard    SD
```

I need to get all distinct title_numbers and then hd_sd will = `HD` if that exists, otherwise, it will = `SD`. The correct output would be:

```
title_number    version_type    hd_sd
1000046         Standard    HD
1000050         Standard    SD
1000093         Standard    HD
1000125         Standard    SD
1000269         Standard    SD
```

The closest I got to this was `SELECT * FROM title GROUP BY title_number`, but that does not give me the correct `hd_sd` column value. How would I correctly do this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT title_NUMBer, Version_type,
        MIN(hd_sd)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY title_NUMBer
```

for improvements,

```
SELECT a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT title_NUMBer, MIN(hd_sd) minCol
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY title_NUMBer
        ) b ON a.title_number = b.title_Number AND
                a.hd_sd = b.mincol
```

Comment: @David542 the first query doesn't give correct details especially with dealing with more columns. the updated one give the correct result. :)